# Generate multiple output files using MultiSinkTap

Tags: java, hadoop, cascading

I had the following dataset as input

```
id,name,gender
asinha161,Aniruddha,Male
vic,Victor,Male
day1,Daisy,Female
jazz030,Jasmine,Female
Mic002,Michael,Male
```

I aimed at segregating the males and females into two separate output files as follows
Dataset for males

```
id,name,gender
asinha161,Aniruddha,Male
vic,Victor,Male
Mic002,Michael,Male
```

Dataset for females

```
id,name,gender
day1,Daisy,Female
jazz030,Jasmine,Female
```

Now, I attempted to write a Cascading Framework code which is supposed to do the above task, the code is as follows

```
public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Tap sourceTap = new FileTap(new TextDelimited(true, ","),       "inputFile.txt");
          Tap sink_one = new FileTap(new TextDelimited(true, ","), "maleFile.txt");
          Tap sink_two = new FileTap(new TextDelimited(true, ","), "FemaleFile.txt");

          Pipe assembly = new Pipe("inputPipe");


          // ...split into two pipes
          Pipe malePipe = new Pipe("for_male", assembly);
          malePipe=new Each(malePipe,new CustomFilterByGender("male"));
          Pipe femalePipe = new Pipe("for_female", assembly);
          femalePipe=new Each(femalePipe, new CustomFilterByGender("female"));
          // create the flow
           List<Pipe> pipes = new ArrayList<Pipe>(2)
        {{pipes.add(countOne);
          pipes.add(countTwo);}};

          Tap outputTap=new MultiSinkTap<>(sink_one,sink_two);

          FlowConnector flowConnector = new LocalFlowConnector();
          Flow flow = flowConnector.connect(sourceTap, outputTap, pipes);
          flow.complete();
      }
```

where CustomFilterByGender(String gender); is a custom function that returns tuples according to the gender value passed as argument.

Please note that I have not used Custom Buffer for the sake of efficiency.

Using MultiSinkTap, I am not able to get the desired output since the `connect()` method of the `LocalFlowConnector` object is not accepting the MultiSinkTap Object which results to a compilation time error. 
It will be imperative if you suggest possible changes in the above code to make it work or the way to use `MultiSinkTap`.
Thankyou for patiently going through the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to write output of different pipes into different output files, I made some changes in your code that should solve your purpose definitely.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Tap sourceTap = new FileTap(new TextDelimited(true, ","), "inputFile.txt");
      Tap sink_one = new FileTap(new TextDelimited(true, ","), "maleFile.txt");
      Tap sink_two = new FileTap(new TextDelimited(true, ","), "FemaleFile.txt");

      Pipe assembly = new Pipe("inputPipe");

      Pipe malePipe = new Pipe("for_male", assembly);
      malePipe=new Each(malePipe,new CustomFilterByGender("male"));
      Pipe femalePipe = new Pipe("for_female", assembly);
      femalePipe=new Each(femalePipe, new CustomFilterByGender("female"));

      List<Pipe> pipes = new ArrayList<Pipe>(2);
      pipes.add(malePipe);
      pipes.add(femalePipe);

      Map<String, Tap> sinks = new HashMap<String, Tap>();
      sinks.put("for_male", sink_one);
      sinks.put("for_female", sink_two);

      FlowConnector flowConnector = new LocalFlowConnector();
      Flow flow = flowConnector.connect(sourceTap, sinks, pipes);
      flow.complete();
  }
```

Instead of using *MultiSinkTap* you can directly give the *Map<>* of Sinks those you want to connect to the output pipes in this case *malePipe* and *femalePipe*.

Comment: Can anyone just tell me the way to use multiSinkTap